# how to count the number of dates in a table

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a small custom blog type site and I keep track of my posts with a `datetime` field in the DB that hold a `current_timestamp` when entered.

I am working on a pagination setup and want to figure out how many unique days there are in my DB.

For example in the below screen shot there are `19` entries but only entered on `5` different days.

[image: date times screenshot]

I want to be able to find the number of unique days in the DB. In the above shot `5`.

This way I can paginate my posts by groups of days, say `7` but still show all the posts for all those days regardless of if one day has more posts or one day has none.

EX for page 1 showing the first 7 days of posts:

Jan 1st
    +post 
    +post
    +post

Jan 3
    +post

Jan 4
    +post
    +post

Jan 5
    +post

Jan 6 
    +post
    +post

Jan 7
    +post

Jan 8
    +post
    +post

How is the best way to get this data or paginate in this way? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the amount of posts per day:

```
select from_days(to_days(date)) day, count(*) from t
group by day
```

You can then apply a limit to the amount of records (days) to paginate them per 7 days:

```
select from_days(to_days(date)) day, count(*) from t
group by day
limit 7
```

Now, if you want to get the actual posts (I think that is what you want), you can do this:

```
select date, file from t t1 join (
  select to_days(date) day from t
  group by day
  order by day desc
  limit 7
) t2
on to_days(t1.date) = t2.day
```

This will give you all posts for the 7 most current days. Is that what you where looking for?

**Edit:**

> I may be misinterpreting or did not ask my question well but I want the the count of all total unique days not posts. - ian

LOL: That's easier :)

```
select count(distinct to_days(date)) from t
```

Comment: I think all of that is what im looking for! The final part returns something like `455` which seems about right.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
select count(*),date from tablename group by left(date,10)
```

above query will give count of unique  days.

Comment: I may be misinterpreting or did not ask my question well but I want the the count of all total unique days not posts.

Comment: ahh... It's ok . I wrote wrong . BTW query is OK but i wrote wrong description it will give count of unique days. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is

`SELECT count(*) from table group by DATE(date)`

the trick is to map `datetime` into `date` via `DATE()` function

UPDATE: sorry I missinterpreted your question. This will return the number of posts in each day.

To get number list of unique days you could do

`SELECT DISTINCT DATE(datetime) from table`

To get number of unique days you could either check the count of it in your back-end language or make a subquery, like:

`select count(*) from (select distinct date(datetime) from table) as res`

Comment: I think this returns the number of posts for each date? I want the number of dates?

Comment: last query returns number of days